# How does HasCallStack influence the performance of a normal branch in Haskell?

Tags: performance, haskell

Generating a call stack when reaching the error branch has runtime cost; that is easy to understand.

But will the `HasCallStack` constraint also influence the performance of a normal branch?  How?

Comment: I guess more information has to be kept around at runtime, just in case there is an error. We have to regard "normal branches", as computations which have not reached an error, but might be in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The effect of adding a `HasCallStack` constraint to a function `foo` is more or less equivalent to:

- adding an additional input argument for the call stack to `foo`'s argument list;
- wherever `foo` is invoked, constructing a call stack argument for it, by pushing an information frame (consisting of the function name "foo" and the source location where it was invoked) onto the input call stack (if `foo` is invoked from another function with a `HasCallStack` constraint) or onto an empty call stack (if it is invoked from a function without a `HasCallStack` constraint).

So... if you have some functions:

```
foo :: HasCallStack => Int -> String -> String
foo n = bar n '*'

bar :: HasCallStack => Int -> Char -> String -> String
bar n c str = if n >= 0 then c' ++ ' ':str ++ ' ':c'
              else error "bad n"
  where c' = replicate n c

baz :: String
baz = foo 3 "hello"
```

then adding `HasCallStack` to `foo` and `bar` (but leaving `baz` alone) has basically the same effect as if you'd written:

```
foo cs n = bar cs' n
  where cs' = pushCallStack ("bar", <loc>) cs
bar cs n c str
  = if n >= 0 then c' ++ ' ':str ++ ' ':c'
    else error cs' "bad n"
  where c' = replicate n c
        cs' = pushCallStack ("error", <loc>) cs
baz = foo cs' 3 "hello"
  where cs' = pushCallStack ("foo", <loc>) emptyCallStack
```

So, the baseline, unoptimized performance cost is the cost of an extra parameter for each function decorated with `HasCallStack` plus the cost of a thunk allocation to supply that parameter for every invocation point of the decorated function.  (These costs are paid even if no error is triggered.)

In practice, optimized code will be... erm... optimized.  For example, if the above example is compiled with `-O2`, `foo` will be inlined and `bar` will be specialized in the definition of `baz` in such a way that the only runtime cost of the call stack is that a static pointer (to a thunk for creating the full call stack for the `error` call) gets passed to the specialized version of `bar` (but ignored, since no error is generated).

GHC doesn't seem to be smart enough to determine that `baz` will never follow the `error` case and so doesn't need the stack frame at all.

Comment: So, adding `HasCallStack` to total function could be optmized as if there is no `HasCallStack`, but GHC is not smart enough to optmize it this much,  so even adding `HasCallStack` to total function also has runtime overhead now, right?

Comment: Well, I think GHC can do better with "statically total" functions where no analysis of the runtime behavior is needed; such functions would still take an extra argument but, if inlined, might have the call stack optimized away.  I don't think you can rely on it, though.